# Datatriggers access and set custom Properties of a UserControl within the style of a child Control

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` that has two custom properties `CustomA` and `CustomB`. I want to use DataTriggers within my `Label` control inside my `UserControl`, to change the `Value` of these custom properties.

In my example, I can't seem to or don't know how to get access to `CustomB` Property in the Setter, so that I can change it's `Value` when the `Value` of `CustomA` Property changes in the DataTrigger. I think the binding for `CustomA` Property is correct, but I don't know what to use for the Setter to get access to `CustomB`.

To sum it up, I need to know how I can get access to my custom properties belonging to my `UserControl` from within the Style DataTriggers of a control - in this case a `Label` - and also change their values

**UCLabel.xaml - UserControl**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="UCLabel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProgram"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="100">

<Label Name="lbl">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=CustomA}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="CustomB" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
</UserControl>
```

**UCLabel.xaml.vb - Code Behind**

```vb
Imports System.Windows
Public Class UCLabel

  'CustomA'
  Public Shared ReadOnly CustomAProperty As DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CustomA",
                                    GetType(Boolean),
                                    GetType(UCLabel), New PropertyMetadata(False))

  Public Property CustomA As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(GetValue(CustomAProperty))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(CustomAProperty, value)
    End Set
  End Property

  'CustomB'
  Public Shared ReadOnly CustomBProperty As DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CustomB",
                                    GetType(Boolean),
                                    GetType(UCLabel), New PropertyMetadata(False))

  Public Property CustomB As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(GetValue(CustomBProperty))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(CustomBProperty, value)
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I think you need to be more realistic. You can simply Bind these two properties with a converter in the code.You might even not need two properties.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to know if it was possible to do it that way! By converter, you mean that when the value of CustomA property changes in the Convert/ConvertBack Methods that I should change the value of CustomB Property there too? I thought converters were for converting values from one type to another like string to boolean, and not for setting values of different/multiple Properties

Comment: if this is the scenario: when CustomA is true, you like CustomB to be false and vice versa. Bind them together and an IValueConverter can do this job.

Comment: So I would use MultiBinding with a Converter, but do I need to use IMultiValueConverter as there are two values that need to be changed? Could I also introduce more Properties later for binding? The main idea I was going for was to change the value of one property which would then change the values of many others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a `Setter` in Style, it means changing the property of the current control(in your case, it is Label), and cannot change the property of any other controls. However, you can achieve your goal by `Behaviors`.

Firstly, you need add the following assembly references to your project:

```
System.Windows.Interactivity
Microsoft.Expression.Interactions
```

Then using the following code:

```
<UserControl
    x:Name="uc"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

    <Label>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="True">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction
                    PropertyName="ProB"
                    TargetName="uc"
                    Value="True" />
            </ei:DataTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Label>
```